# Where Are the Children for Ding Dong Dell "043 Hide and Seek"?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

A mother in Ding Dong Dell is asking that I find her **three missing sons**.  Where are each of them located?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first one is by the shrine.  The second one is on top of a tower.  The third one is in the weapons shop.

Comment: The one by the "tower" is nearest to where the mother gives the errand. Look for a ramp to climb up on the minimap. He is probably the hardest one to locate as he doesn't show up on the map until you climb up top.

Comment: Strangely enough, this was the one that I found first, probably due to his proximity to the mother. The one that gave me trouble was the one in the Cawtermaster's, since I hadn't yet been in there, and I was looking **everywhere** that I could go in town except there.